# Get object from Hashmap which contains needed information?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Object>`. `Object` contains of information like: `name`, `surname` and `unique ID`. How to get only that objects, which contains For Example: specific `surname`?

Comment: I guess you've tried anything already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter your list:

```
HashMap<String, YourObject> input =...;
```

If you want a list of Object:

```
List<YourObject> result = input.values().stream()
              .filter(o -> o.getSurname().equals("your filter surname"))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a hashmap of your object

```
Map<String, YourObject> result = input.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(e -> e.getValue().getSurname().equals("your filter surname"))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You're welcome~. Please post your specific output and input next time. The community will have struggle time to guess what you wanna do haha

Answer (score 0):

Store the object in the HashMap using the surname as the key

```
HashMap<String, List<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.putIfAbsent(myobj.surname, new List<MyObject>();
map.put(myobj.surname, map.get(myobj.surname).add(myobj));

map.get("surname");
```

Comment: In this case values for surname property should be unique for all objects or type of `HashMap` should be `HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>

Comment: I've included your suggestion in my answer